# How to change payment mode for a form created via infusion

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, infusionsoft

My default currency of my infusion account is in GBP. However, I want to change it to USD for a particular form. Is there a way of achieving that?
The form itself has been created via infusion. I don't want to change the default currency settings. Infusion supports one currency at a time, so they were not much of a help. Pls assist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way in this case is to use custom order form (not Infusionsoft form) that submits data to Infusionsoft using API.

I've also met such solutions:

1. use different Infusionsoft accounts per currency
2. use  [javascript](http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/17642-Currency-issues?p=42652&viewfull=1#post42652) to change currency symbols
3. use different Infusionsoft products if you need them to be setup in different currencies prices.